# telerik ribbonview itemsource binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

I am trying to bind itemssource property of RibbonView with a collection. The binding is working fine I am able to get no. of tabs equivalent to number of items in collection.

But I am not able see the content inside ribbontab. I tried using templateselector but didnt worked. Could you please guide how to load contents and header of ribbontab dynamically from collection.

Regards,
Sanjay

Comment: Hi, did you have a look at Telerik's Getting Started tutorial? Maybe it helps: http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radribbonview-gettingstarted.html

Comment: I checked that it only says you can add a collection to Itemsource. I did that now tabs are created but how to load usercontrol inside each tabitem content?